# Opening a file for appending

Tags: python-2.7, nonetype, errno

EDIT: I seem to have fixed it in an adhoc way. I do see this as a practical solution, but it is an unacceptable answer. All I added was an fp.read() statement before the write. Can anyone explain why this would avoid Errno 0? That is what happens without the fp.read() line.

I've been trying to make a script which appends a bit of html code to my notes file every day. I have trouble updating the file though. I have tried all of the `open()` tags (`r`, `w`, `a`, `r+` etc...).

Code:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    bs=BeautifulSoup

```
import datetime

with open("crossfireNewNotes.html",'a+') as fp:
    soup= bs(fp,"lxml")
    print "8 " + str(soup)
    print "9 " + str(soup.html)


    today=str(datetime.date.today())
    print "11 " + str(soup) 
    if soup.select("body#" + today) ==[]:

        new_body=soup.new_tag("body",id=today)
        new_p=soup.new_tag("p")
        new_olink=soup.new_tag("a",link=today)
        new_ilink=soup.new_tag("a",href=today)

        soup.html.append(new_body)
        soup.html.select("body#" + today)[0].append(new_olink)
        soup.html.select("body#" + today)[0].select("a[link=" + today + "]").append(new_p)
        soup.body.insert_before(new_ilink)

        print "25 " + str(soup) 

        fp.read()
        fp.write(str(soup))
        fp.close()
```

Before, the file object was a NoneType, giving me other issues. Now it seems to open fine, but I have the following output in cmd:

```
Line 8: <html></html>
Line 11: <html></html>
Line 25: <html><a href="2018-08-18"></a><body id="2018-08-18"><a link="2018-08-18"></a></body></html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "noter.py", line 29, in (module)
     fp.write(str(soup))
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Alternatively, if anyone has any better methods I am open to them.

Comment: From what you've given here, it seems like an indentation problem. You need to continue the indentation of `with`, otherwise the file `fp` will be prematurely closed.

Comment: I did already try that. It didn't change anything. If you run the code you will notice that the 8th line print statement prints nothing for str(soup), so even within the statement it thinks it's empty.

Comment: `mode='a'` is for append.  `a+` is not a thing, don't do that.

Comment: False: Modes "'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing)"- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering lies between opening the filehandler `fp` in `append` mode and moving the pointer around via the `soup.html.append` and `soup.html.select` methods. As soon as you want to write to file, your pointer is no longer at the end of the file. If you `read()` the file, then the pointer is yet again at the end and thus you can write again. A better method would be to [`fp.seek(0,2)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to find the end of your file.

Better yet, you could first load the content of your html file into BeautifulSoup, do the changes, and then write from the soup object to file, thus using two separate file IOs.